Is it possible that systemctl process would not run without me being logged in to the server?
I am very new to linux and I need some help. I am trying to put blockchain node processes on the background so that they run without my being logged in.
I am using systemctl to run my process in the background.
Here are my .service files
Root dir, command, identifiers and user were just redacted from the file they are not being imported. Also the cmds work in the "foreground" that being when I simply run them in the terminal.
1st
[Unit]
Description=MY_DESC
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=USER
WorkingDirectory=ROOT_DIR
ExecStart=MY_COOL_CMD
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SyslogIdentifier=MY_ID
StartLimitInterval=0
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitNPROC=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

2nd service file
[Unit]
Description=MY_DESC
After=network.target 1st-service.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=USER
WorkingDirectory=HOME_DIR
Environment="DAEMON_NAME=CMD_DIR"
Environment="DAEMON_HOME=HOME_DIR"
Environment="DAEMON_ALLOW_DOWNLOAD_BINARIES=false"
Environment="DAEMON_RESTART_AFTER_UPGRADE=true"
Environment="UNSAFE_SKIP_BACKUP=true"
ExecStart=MY_COOL_CMD
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SyslogIdentifier=MY_ID
StartLimitInterval=0
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitNPROC=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I enabled both files successfully. They seem to be running when I am logged in, but not when I am away. There are no errors, but when I check the logs the block numbers did not rack up enough (last time it has been a week since I have been logged out and the block height has jumped up only by 100,000 blocks. Which is not a lot). Also when try to check the logs in the past (between 6 and 7 hours ago) the logs show no entry...
Here is what I get when I ask for status
1st
my.service - MY_DESC
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-11-29 22:57:00 CET; 1 week 0 days ago
   Main PID: 1940037 (geth)
      Tasks: 23 (limit: 19099)
     Memory: 9.8G
        CPU: 4d 21h 2min 16.071s
     CGroup: /system.slice/my.service
             └─1940037 MY_COOL_CMD

2nd file
my.service - my
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-11-29 23:02:23 CET; 1 week 0 days ago
   Main PID: 1940098 (cosmovisor)
      Tasks: 28 (limit: 19099)
     Memory: 4.7G
        CPU: 3d 4h 49min 4.542s
     CGroup: /system.slice/my.service
             ├─1940098 CMD_HERE
             └─1940111 CMD_HERE

That is when I am logged in.
If there is anything else that you need to see to give me some guidance in this matter please let me know.
Thank you very much for your time and expertise!

What kind of system? Is this your PC, is this a dedicated server, or a VPS, or an Openvz container, or something else?

This question is similar to: Make user systemd service persistent. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@grawity It is a VPS running ubuntu 22.04.5.

@muru thank you for bringing that to my attention. I am currently trying the solution presented in the post provided. But my services are not user-services, that is why I am afraid the solution provided in that post will not be applicable.

What kind of VPS? was my question.

@tonymasek sure, but it looks like your services have dependencies on the user - maybe a home directory or something that only gets mounted when the user logs in?

I can't be sure from the info in your question, but my best guess is that you've created a "user-service"; aka "user units", or "rootless". One way to determine if yours is a "user-service" is if you must use the --user option to control it using various systemctl commands; e.g.
systemctl enable {your-service-name} 
# vs.
systemctl --user enable {your-service-name}

Another way to tell (while you're logged in and your service is running) is which one of the following outputs your service appears under:
$ systemctl --user --type=service --state=running

# vs.

$ systemctl --type=service --state=running

If it appears under the --user option above, then yours is a "user-service". "user-services" are typically set up/configured by default to run only as long as the designated user has an active login on the system; they stop running after the last user login has been terminated.
AFAIK, there are (may be) two (2) ways to circumvent this behavior:
1. modify the getty@tty1.service
This method is a bit of a hack I picked up in the Debian forums some time ago. It still works reliably; I use it with pipewire to keep the music playing after I logout:
# open the 'getty@tty1.service' file in your editor:
 
$ sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1.service

# In the [Service] section, add the following two lines: 

ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I $TERM 

# save changes and exit the editor...

$ sudo reboot

# after 'reboot', you can test :

$ who
pi       tty1         1970-01-10 21:45             # <=== this!
pi       pts/0        -3386239902218585523 (192.168.1.209)

NOTE: I've included this 2nd technique (loginctl), but I only recently learned of it from this Baeldung article. I haven't actually tried it yet!
2. use loginctl
From the command line, use loginctl w/ the enable-linger option (see man loginctl for details); e.g.:
$ loginctl enable-linger [USER...]    #  (see 'man loginctl') 


Thank you Seamus. My services show up only after i run systemctl --type=service --state=running. So now I can be certain that the services are not user-services. Which would bring me back to the core issue. But thank you for your time!

@tonymasek: OK - thanks for letting me know, but you might try the suggested answer anyway.  If the issue is that the service won't run without the user being logged in, the getty@tty1.service should take care of that. I really only mentioned the user-services bit because that's the only place I've seen it come up.
